# "The merchandise variant referenced by this term condition could not be found" - Shopify API Error

Tags: python, shopify, fastapi, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am creating a custom app on shopify and trying to create a draft order. When I create the draft order, I get the following error.

```
{
  "errors": {
    "base": [
      "The merchandise variant referenced by this term condition could not be found."
    ]
  }
}
```

The code that I have written is as follows:

```
# Create a Shopify session 
        access_token = '<ACCESS_TOKEN>'
        shop_url = "<URL>"
        # session = shopify.Session(cart.storeId, GLOBAL_SHOPIFY_API_VERSION, access_token)
        # shopify.ShopifyResource.activate_session(session)

        # # Create a new draft order
        # new_draft_order = shopify.DraftOrder()
        # new_draft_order.line_items = {
        #     "variant_id": cart.cartItem.get("variantId"),
        #     "quantity": cart.cartItem.get("quantity")
        # }
        # await new_draft_order.save()

        # Set the headers and the data for the request
        headers = {
            'X-Shopify-Access-Token': access_token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }

        json_data = {
            'draft_order': {
                'line_items': [
                    {
                        'varianct_id': cart.cartItem.get("variantId"),
                        'quantity': cart.cartItem.get("quantity"),
                    },
                ],
            },
        }

        response = requests.post(
            f'https://{shop_url}/admin/api/{GLOBAL_SHOPIFY_API_VERSION}/draft_orders.json',
            headers=headers,
            json=json_data,
        )

        # Check if the request was successful
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response.json()
        
        if response.status_code == 202:
            return response.json()
        
        return response.json()
```

I have used the API Access token for the endpoint so it should be working. The variant ID is also correct and can be viewed on the shopify platform.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the variant ID. Did you use the GID or just the plain jane Shopify legacy resource one?

```
"gid://shopify/Product/10079785100"

versus just 10079785100
```

It might be that...

Comment: I used the simple legacy one because that's mentioned in the documentation. I am not using graph QL by the way. I am using REST APIs only.

Comment: Ok.. ya.. now that I look at your URL it is not graphql.json... carry on then. Have fun!